# Change print dialogue box

Tags: ms-access-2010

My form, which is called "Production Info", has a button on it that prints only the current record when clicked. I have added to its Onclick macro so that as well as printing when clicked, it also opens a second form and prints that as well. However, I am still getting two separate print dialogue boxes. Is there a way to print them both from the same print dialogue box so that the reports print together (duplex print) on the same paper instead of printing separately on different pages?

Also, I know it is not common practice to print forms, but making the "Production Info" form into a report isn't an option because it has a combo box that is essential to its' functionality. I tried making it a report before, but reports don't support interactive controls as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such option.

You could print to two PDF files, then use a PDF tool to merge these into one PDF-file, and finally print this.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I will try to do. As far as you know is it possible to do this PDF conversion/print by using a macro? I would like for the user not to have to do anything apart from pushing a button.

Comment: Yes, though not a five-minutes job. One option could be to use a PDF tool that can be controlled from the command line. [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) is one such (free) tool. An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445164/3527297).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I really appreciate it!